# How to store the barcode only as a .png instead of on a A4 page using rghost?

Tags: ruby, barcode

I'm using [rghost-barcode](https://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost-barcode) to generate an Aztec barcode. But every time I create a barcode it get's saved on a full A4 page with the barcode at the top left.

Why is this happening? How do I save the barcode only to the PNG with the dimensions I want (720px x 720px).

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
doc = RGhost::Document.new

doc.barcode_azteccode('This is Aztec Code',{:text=>{:size=>8}, :format=>"full"})
doc.render :png, :resolution => 100, :filename => "my_barcode.png"
```

And this is the result:

[image: my_barcode result]

Comment: Can you change the document size when you initialize it?

Answer (score 1):

The gem uses postscript/ghostsript as backend, so it is always producing documents, and then inserts barcodes into this document. And these document seem to have A4 as default.

According the [rghost wiki](https://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost/wiki/Paper-and-Page-Layout), you can specify how big the document should be:

```
doc = RGhost::Document.new :paper => [15,10]
```

I'm afraid the dimension is in inches (the wiki does not state the dimension)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the paper size *and* position your barcode. Notice that the y positioning of the barcode is from the bottom of the page. After a bit of trial and error, this works fine for example:

```
#paper is x , y
doc=RGhost::Document.new :paper => [4.4, 3.2]
#y is from bottom of page
doc.barcode_ean13('2112345678900',
  {:text=>{:size=>7}, 
   :enable=>[:text], 
   :scale=>[1,1], 
   :x => 0.5, :y => 0.4})
doc.render :png, :resolution => 100, :filename => "ean13.png"
```

If you want to increase the resolution of the code, just doubling the scale, as well as all the others parameters (paper size, and barcode x, y) should work.